# Propose Renaming “wpfstyle” tag to “wpf-style”

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I think maybe the [wpfstyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpfstyle) tag name should be changed to [wpf-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf-style) on Stack Overflow. I almost didn't find it. The dashed format seems to be more consistent with most of the other tags I encounter.