# Rename [wpfgrid] to [wpf-grid]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There was a similar [request to rename **wpfstyle** to **wpf-style**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305886/propose-renaming-wpfstyle-tag-to-wpf-style), so I think the same should be considered for the [wpfgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpfgrid) tag.

We also have such tags as [wpf-textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf-textbox) and [wpf-listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf-listview). To keep it consistent, I propose to rename [wpfgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpfgrid) to **wpf-grid**.

E.g. [wpflocalizationextension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpflocalizationextension) and [wpftoolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpftoolkit) tags are related to corresponding products. [wpfgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpfgrid) could be slightly misleading - one could suppose there is a product with such name, whereas it's just a WPF UI element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have mixed feelings about having a tag for `Grid` in WPF (and even the tag for WPF styles seems better repurposed as one for XAML styles, even if implementations differ between WPF and WinRT), but then again, [html-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-table) exists. In any case, I've renamed the tag for now.